# Can I see tag upvotes per day?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, up-votes

The user stats page, and the tag page list upvotes over the last 30 days, and all time.  Is is possible to see these numbers over smaller timeframes, like per day, or per week?

The rep graph shows this kind of information for rep; is there an analogous tool for tag upvotes?

This certainly isn't a feature request; the team has much, much better things to do.  I'm just wondering if this already exists somewhere.

Would this be **possible** with a data query?

Comment: I had this same question today. I'm sure it's possible with Data.SE, but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Votes in a tag per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/244938/votes-in-a-tag-per-day)

The data is based on the current tags of the post, not at the tags at the time of the vote. Doing it right is impossible from the public data since the time of votes is rounded to the nearest day. Doing it approximately right (based on the tag at the start of the day) would be possible but hard. Also, with public data, posts that are now deleted are not taken into account.